# How to override Elmah applicationname set in Web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, elmah

We have a multi-tenanted MVC app, meaning that exactly the same app is published to multiple IIS virtual directories / applications, and then the app its self works out who it is, and skins its self (css) accordingly.

This is all very well, but anything logged by ELMAH in our elmah database gets logged under the same applicationName, as this is pulled out of Web.Config elmah section below where everything would be logged as "MyappName" :

```
<configuration>
  [...]
  <elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="false" /> 
    <errorLog 
        type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" 
        connectionStringName="elmah" 
        applicationName="MyappName" />
  </elmah>
</configuration>
```

The question is therefore how to override the applicationName setting from web.config with something specific so we can distinguish errors for a given tenant web site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is configurable within the web.config, ELMAH are already providing you with a way to specify the application name when the application is deployed to different locations - it's just a case of making use of it.

This would generally be something that you would manipulate as part of your deployment steps.  If you are doing it manually then it's going to be a pain, but it could be easily manipulated by using a web.config transform.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <elmah>
        <errorLog applicationName="MyappName" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </elmah>
</configuration>
```

I wonder if the following might work, if you put the following into your Global.asax:

```
var service = ServiceCenter.Current;

ServiceCenter.Current = context =>
{
    var connectionString = "YOUR CONNECTION STRING";
    var container = new ServiceContainer(service(context));
    var log = new SqlErrorLog(connectionString) { ApplicationName = "APP NAME HERE" };
    container.AddService(typeof(ErrorLog), log);
    return container;
};
```

Comment: Hi Luke thanks for the input. Unfortunately this wouldn't work as we don't have a transform per customer (i.e. tenant), and it's basically the customer / tenant name I want shown in ELMAH.
We're using transforms for the differences between the DEV, UAT and LIVE environments but not per customer as we don't want 200+ project configurations & therefore possible transforms.

Comment: This is something that could be easily automated during your deployments, if you know which tenant is being deployed to which locations, it's the perfect opportunity to patch the configs with the right details.

Comment: I've just added some code that I wonder if it will work.  I've assumed that you're logging to SQL though.

Comment: Hi Luke thanks for that - works a treat! Where on earth did you get that from? Anyway - cheers, and have some points :)

Comment: haha, it took quite a bit of searching.  I found one where someone was setting the connection string dynamically and just stumbled upon the `ApplicationName` property being exposed on that object.  I'm really pleased that it worked. :o)

Comment: Me too Luke :) [Doffs hat]